# Split 1-column dataframe rows by row index into new columns

Tags: pandas, split

I have a pandas dataframe y_all with 1 column and 13400 rows. I want to split the 13400 rows into 10 columns (y0-y9) with 1340 rows each by using the row index. I tried something like this but I want the shortest and cleanest code possible.

```
y0, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7, y8, y9 = y_all[:1340], y_all[1340:2680].reset_index(drop=True),
                                             y_all[2680:4020].reset_index(drop=True), y_all[4020:5360].reset_index(drop=True),
                                             y_all[5360:6700].reset_index(drop=True), y_all[6700:8040].reset_index(drop=True),
                                             y_all[8040:9380].reset_index(drop=True), y_all[9380:10720].reset_index(drop=True),
                                             y_all[10720:12060].reset_index(drop=True), y_all[12060:].reset_index(drop=True)

_y_all = pd.concat([y0,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9],axis=1)
```

Please advise.

Cheers

Comment: what is the column name for y_all?

Comment: please provide more guidance if my answer is correct.

Comment: Hi James sorry for the delay, the column name is just '0'. I see your solution I will try it out later today. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner that will produce what you desire. You must replace `'your_column'` with the column name you have in `y_all`. The theory is to concatenate multiple pandas series that are generated by [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), where the iterable is using the function [np.array_split()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) which will split your single column into 10 equal sized arrays.

```
_y_all = pd.concat([pd.Series(j, name='y' + str(i), index=range(0,1340)) for i,j in enumerate(np.array_split(y_all['your_column'].values, 10))], axis=1)
```